# How to run file in strawberry perl portable 5.10.0.1 with arguments?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

[screen image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAP76.jpg)
Hi can someone tell me how to run a perl program with arguments in strawberry perl portable?

The problem is that before we were using DZsoft where there is an icon "run in command prompt" in "arguments:"we typed input file and output file and log name, and the perl pre-processor does the rest and creates the files in the same dir. 
But in strawberry perl portable it must be done in cmd with commands that i don't know?
Can someone help with this?
Thanks

Comment: What does "running with attribute mean"?

Comment: "arguments" my mistake sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Answer is

perl 4666513.pp(name of program) INVO_0423.xml(name of file) INVO_0423.out log.txt

very simple indeed...